# Release Mouse Capture

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, rdp

I have an issue while using RDP and I fear the only solution is to run RDP via VMWare or similar.

I have some automated software that takes control of the mouse and executes various scripts on the remote machine. In order for me to start this I press a key which executes the software and takes over the mouse control. This prevents me from using my computer while I am connected to the remote machine as my mouse movements interrupt the script.

The problem is RDP appears to capture the mouse as soon as you hover over it. There is no way to release the mouse capture like you can with VMWare etc. Ideally a "click" to capture feature would be best. If it was available but so far my googles have failed.

Does anyone know a potential solution?

Comment: Are you trying to be able to use your local machine after kicking off the script? But you're unable to because remote desktop will capture any mouse movement on your local? is your automated software moving your local mouse or your remote mouse?

Comment: The software is executed on the remote machine. So that will begin moving the mouse on the remote machine. So whenever the mouse cursor is hovered over on RDP on the window, it will interfere with the automation. I do not need to use the machine whilst the script is active. But I do need to observe and be able to disable the mouse capture so I do not accidentally disturb it. This can be achieved in VMWare with ALT+CTRL

https://www.vmware.com/support/ws4/doc/running_prefs_ws.html

Comment: RDP Software that has some sort of mouse capture feature would work great - but It doesn't seem to be available in anything I have tried yet.

Comment: i see. one thing taht may be a workaround is to minimize your rdp once you kick off the script and use windows aero peek to glance at what your remote is doing. other than that, i do not know what you can do :(

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd> - this will release keyboard and mouse capture